# Strange compiler behavior with generics: Narrowing return type arguments on inheritance

Tags: java, generics

On overriding, no additional type variable is needed for narrowing the return type of a super method, if it concerns the raw/unerased type only. Example: [Narrowing return types on inheritance (generics involved)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140455/narrowing-return-types-on-inheritance-generics-involved)

But if a type argument is narrowed - while the raw type stays the same -, an additional method type variable is needed.

Example:

```
import java.util.List;

public class InheritanceTest {

    public interface A<T> {

        A<T> test();

        List<A<T>> testList1();

        <U extends A<T>> List<U> testList2();

        <U> List<A<T>> testList3();

        // extending class/interface does not need to suppress warnings:
        List<? extends A<T>> testList4();
    }

    public interface B extends A<Integer> {

        @Override
        B test();

        @Override
        List<B> testList1();

        @Override @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<B> testList2();

        @Override @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<B> testList3();

        @Override
        List<B> testList4();
    }
}
```

The compiler complains about incompatible return types for `testList1()`, but does not report any error for the remaining three methods. `

How does the unused variable in `testList3()` make the compiler shut up?

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Comment: Thank you. I simplified the example.

Comment: "Two methods or constructors, M and N, have the same signature if they have the same name, the same type parameters (if any) (§8.4.4), and, after adapting the formal parameter types of N to the the type parameters of M, the same formal parameter types." If you don't have the same type parameters, they're not override-equivalent.

Comment: I just realized that as well, but I can't explain why the `@Override` does not throw an error.

Comment: @AndyTurner look around the last code block in my answer, maybe that triggers something in your brain.

Comment: @JornVernee ^^^

Answer (score 1):

When you're overriding a method with a covariant return type, you're essentially saying that the overridden return type is a subclass of the super return type. Meaning `List<B>` is assignable to `List<A<T>>`, which is not true. Here's a simple example without method declarations using your types (`A<T>` and `B`; what methods they have don't matter here):

```
List<A<Integer>> listOfA;
List<B> listOfB =  new ArrayList<>();
listOfA = listOfB; // compile error: incompatible types: List<B> cannot be converted to List<A<Integer>>

List<? extends A<Integer>> listOfAFixed;
listOfAFixed = listOfB;
```

... and the reason why this assignment is not allowed, because there could be a `C extends A<Integer>` which would introduce a potential for a ClassCastException

```
List<C> listOfC =  new ArrayList<>();
listOfA = listOfC; // let's assume this compiles
B b = getAB();
listOfA.add(b); // adding to listOfC, right?
C c = listOfC.get(0); // whops, ClassCastException
```

you can replace `A<T>` with `Number`, `B` with `Integer` and `C` with `Float`; the same thing will happen. **The problem is not with the generics on `A`, but with the generics of the `List`.**

Using the same logic I tried to reproduce the other covariant overrides (~assignments) in method bodies as well, but they didn't give a warning but an error as well. It's odd.

**One thing to realize is that removing the parameter from `A` still gives the same warnings**:

```
public interface A {
    <U extends A> List<U> testList2();
    <U> List<A> testList3();
}

public interface B extends A {
    @Override List<B> testList2();
    @Override List<B> testList3();
}
```

I think the trick lies in the fact that the overriding methods are not "generic enough" (lack of better terminology I know), look at the internal signatures listed by `javap`:

```
<U::LInheritanceTest$A;>()Ljava/util/List<TU;>;
()Ljava/util/List<LInheritanceTest$B;>;

<U:Ljava/lang/Object;>()Ljava/util/List<LInheritanceTest$A;>;
()Ljava/util/List<LInheritanceTest$B;>;
```

Notice that the overriding methods lack `<>`, which I guess is similar to using raw types and hence the unchecked warning instead of the error: it uses the partially erased type.

This is the point where I give up, maybe Andy or Jorn can make this more officially explained.

Answer (score 0):

In cases where raw and generic types mix, the language spec gives up. To do otherwise would introduce even more obscure rules, all to support situations which should be avoided.

`A.testList3` is a generic method. `B` attempts to declare the same method (same name, same erased types as parameters and return) as non-generic. So, it appears that the language spec ignores all the generics leaving the methods compatible.

(So heed, don't suppress, warnings.)

Comment: This does not answer my question about `A.testList3`, because what you say is true for `A.testList1`, too: Here, the problem can only be solved by changing the line to `List<? extends A<T>> testList1();`.